# How to increase detail level in Capistrano output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**1) Context**

While deploying a Spree site, `cap deploy` returns the following error message:

```
[err :: 000.000.000.000] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby /var/www/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake requirejs:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

I have posted more of the output of `cap deploy` under 4), at the end of this message.

Notes:

1a) Navigating to the production site, I see that most assets are missing, which confirms that the assets precompile phase has been aborted.

1b) Cap deploys displays a success message just before exiting, see the output post under 4)

**2) My question**

How can I tweek Capistrano and Rake to obtain more information about the failure ? Is it possible to set the log level of Capistrano and its tool stack to debug or even info ?

**3) What I have already tried, without success**

3a) When invoked from the command line, both on the development box and on the production server, this rake task ends without an error message.

3b) `rake --trace` just lists the tasks that are invoked / executed, again no error message.

3c) adding the following initializer did not help either:

```
  # config/initializers/assets_logging.rb
  Rails.application.assets.logger = Logger.new($stdout)
  Rails.application.assets.logger.level = 0
```

3d) the application works fine in development mode and my bundle is up to date.
I list the Gemfile under section 4), maybe it will provide a hint

**4) Additional information**

Contents of my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end # group :assets do

group :development do
  gem 'xray-rails'
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.15.5'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano', '~> 1.4.1'
  gem 'diffy'
  gem 'thin'
end # group :development do

group :production do
  gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter', '~> 0.0.1'
end # group :production do

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'pg'
gem 'spree_i18n', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_i18n.git', :branch => '2-0-stable'
gem 'squeel'
gem 'capistrano-log_with_awesome'

# private library 
gem 'myprivatelibrary', path: "/home/user/myprivatelibrary/"

gem 'requirejs-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.2.1'
gem 'spree', '2.0.3'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => '2-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-0-stable'
```

Output of `cap deploy` (to easily spot the error, look for the only line with three stars, i.e.  `***` at the beginning):

```
    triggering load callbacks
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
  * getting (via checkout) revision  to /tmp/20131212195216
    executing locally: cp -R . /tmp/20131212195216
    command finished in 457ms
  * Compressing /tmp/20131212195216 to /tmp/20131212195216.tar.gz
    executing locally: tar czf 20131212195216.tar.gz 20131212195216
    command finished in 11527ms
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
 ** sftp upload /tmp/20131212195216.tar.gz -> /tmp/20131212195216.tar.gz
    [87.98.157.252] /tmp/20131212195216.tar.gz
    [87.98.157.252] done
  * sftp upload complete
  * executing "cd /var/www/site/releases && tar xzf /tmp/20131212195216.tar.gz && rm /tmp/20131212195216.tar.gz"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
    command finished in 901ms
  * executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216 && bundle install --gemfile /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216/Gemfile --path /var/www/site/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
    command finished in 2087ms
  * executing `deploy:assets:symlink'
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216/public/assets && mkdir -p /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216/public && mkdir -p /var/www/site/shared/assets && ln -s /var/www/site/shared/assets /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216/public/assets"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
    command finished in 253ms
  * executing "chmod -R -- g+w /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216 && rm -rf -- /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216/public/system && mkdir -p -- /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216/public/ && ln -s -- /var/www/site/shared/system /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216/public/system && rm -rf -- /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216/log && ln -s -- /var/www/site/shared/log /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216/log && rm -rf -- /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216/tmp/pids && mkdir -p -- /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216/tmp/ && ln -s -- /var/www/site/shared/pids /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216/tmp/pids"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
    command finished in 310ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing `deploy:assets:update_asset_mtimes'
  * executing "[ -e /var/www/site/shared/assets/manifest* ] && cat /var/www/site/shared/assets/manifest* || echo"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
    command finished in 527ms
 ** Updating mtimes for ~2976 assets...
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
 ** scp upload #<StringIO:0x00000001567d58> -> /var/www/site/TOUCH_ASSETS
    [87.98.157.252] /var/www/site/TOUCH_ASSETS
  * scp upload complete
  * executing "cat /var/www/site/TOUCH_ASSETS | while read asset; do touch -c -- \"$asset\"; done && rm -f -- /var/www/site/TOUCH_ASSETS"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
    command finished in 2694ms
  * executing "cd -- /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216 && RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
*** [err :: 87.98.157.252] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby /var/www/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake requirejs:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
    command finished in 116488ms
  * executing "ls -1 /var/www/site/shared/assets/manifest* | wc -l"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
    command finished in 245ms
  * executing "ls /var/www/site/shared/assets/manifest*"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
    command finished in 271ms
  * executing "ls -x /var/www/site/releases"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
    command finished in 247ms
  * executing "cp -- /var/www/site/shared/assets/manifest.yml /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216/assets_manifest.yml"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
    command finished in 244ms
  * executing `deploy:create_symlink'
  * executing "rm -f /var/www/site/current &&  ln -s /var/www/site/releases/20131212195216 /var/www/site/current"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
    command finished in 258ms
 ** transaction: commit
  * executing `deploy:restart'
  * executing "touch /var/www/site/current/tmp/restart.txt"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
    command finished in 247ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:restart'
  * executing `deploy:cleanup'
  * executing "ls -1dt /var/www/site/releases/* | tail -n +6 |  xargs rm -rf"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
    command finished in 336ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:cleanup'
  * executing `deploy:assets:clean_expired'
  * executing "for manifest in /var/www/site/releases/*/assets_manifest.*; do cat -- \"$manifest\" 2> /dev/null && printf ':::' || true; done"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
    command finished in 758ms
 ** Fetched 5 manifests from /var/www/site/releases/*/assets_manifest.*
 ** Writing required assets to /var/www/site/REQUIRED_ASSETS...
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
 ** scp upload #<StringIO:0x000000015b52d8> -> /var/www/site/REQUIRED_ASSETS
    [87.98.157.252] /var/www/site/REQUIRED_ASSETS
  * scp upload complete
 ** Removing assets that haven't been deployed for 10080 minutes...
  * executing "cd -- /var/www/site/ && LC_COLLATE=C sort REQUIRED_ASSETS -o REQUIRED_ASSETS && cd -- /var/www/site/shared/assets/ && for f in $( find * -mmin +10080 -type f | LC_COLLATE=C sort | LC_COLLATE=C comm -23 -- - /var/www/site/REQUIRED_ASSETS ); do echo \"Removing unneeded asset: $f\"; rm -f -- \"$f\"; done; rm -f -- /var/www/site/REQUIRED_ASSETS"
    servers: ["87.98.157.252"]
    [87.98.157.252] executing command
    command finished in 300ms
```

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this problem in removing `requirejs` from my `Gemfile`.